# How to make damped tracking work on individual origins?

Tags: constraints

I have created a simple tree and have planes for the main bushy leaves.

I have applied "damped tracking" to make them always face the camera. This works splendidly for single objects, but when I have multiple planes within an object they follow a single origin. (Instead of rotating in place)

I would like each plane to move on its own origin point without having to make each plane of leaves a seperate object. (If I want to make a forest this would be an unnecessary amount of objects!)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it's doable once those planes are part of a standalone mesh object. This can be done with particle system and its options like in Rotation scroll and Velocity. Thus those planes will be created across the mesh with that particle system and won't exhist as real objects.

Comment: For the planes to have "individual origins" they must be separate objects, otherwise they are just one single mesh with multiple chunks of geometry inside it, not multiple planes, and thus wont have individual origins to rotate about.